# How to allow USB debugging for a specific computer when touch response doesn't work

Tags: android

I am using an e-star tablet(mercury hd quad core) to test my android apps.
I have cracked the screen and the touch response isn't working so i am using a mouse .

I have enabled developer options and USB debugging
[usb debugging enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Wm8.png)

However when i connect my device to the computer i get this popup

[stupid popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvp84.png)

I can't really click it,since I can't use the mouse when the mouse is connected to the computer,and as soon as I disconnect it from the computer,the popup dissappears.

Is there anyway I can click that popup?I am willing to get aditional hardware if necessary.However I would prefer a faster solution.

Comment: Try to use mouse and connect to tablet via network(wifi) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Answer (score 0):

You can connect with TeamViewer

http://www.hintmequick.com/control-android-from-pc-using-teamviewer/

Comment: Please explain how to do it here, not only the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate your screen from all angles, then connect your computer using your USB. When the dialog box pops up, you can choose on always allowing USB debugging from your computer.